# Javascript: quick and dirty empty div or other element

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I often run across a problem where I have used `getElementById` to populate a div or span element, usually via Ajax from the server. However, I would like the user to be able to do something simple to empty out the div and go back to the way the page was before. For example, click somewhere else on the page. I have been resorting to putting a little collapse icon that when clicked reloads the page, but that is clearly not the best solution.

Can anyone suggest a simple way to clear out the div. I have a hunch it is about finding right handler but I don't know to much about handlers. It would be great if this could be in same script but any approach is welcome.

Right now this has come up with a script that grabs a selection and searches with it. If the results are not useful, I'd like to let the user click and empty out the div. However, the problem really comes up all the time. Here is the abbreviated code that I am working on now...

JS

```
function getSelection() {
  var sel = getSelection();
  if (sel=""){
    alert("Please select text");
  } else {
    //grab selection and search on it using Ajax
    //code for browsers...
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        document.getElementById('searchresults').textContent=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","search.php?q="+sel,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="getSelection()">click</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have all the elements to do this. A spin-off of your `getSelection` function:

```
var clear = function(){
  document.getElementById('searchresults').textContent = "";
};
```

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="clear()">clear</a>
```

**Note:** A humble advice: you should graduate from adding inline JS to binding event handlers.

---

One way to clear the contents when a click outside of `searchresults` is detected can be done by stopping the propagation of the event at `searchresults` for any `click` generated under `searchresults`. But, clearing it at `document` level for any `click` outside of `searchresults`.

```
var searchresults = document.getElementById("searchresults")​;
var stop = function(evt){
    evt.stopPropagation();
};
var clear = function(){
    searchresults.innerHTML = "";
};
searchresults.addEventListener("click", stop, false);
document.addEventListener("click", clear, false);
```

To achieve this you need to use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) (and [`attachEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28VS.85%29.aspx), its IE counterpart.)

Comment: Is there a way to trigger the javascript call without having a link "clear" on the page.  I.e. you just click somewhere outside the searchresults.  Or maybe in the search results box but not on one of the individual results which are links to another page?

Comment: @user1904273, for what I can understand you solved your problem but still I can't see you marked any answer (remember you need to do this.) Now, your new question may need more information (For example, the `HTML` layout) and you should consider resolving this one and posting a new one with appropriate information and updated code as you have right now

Comment: Apologies.  I already use document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = "" quite a lot when someone clicks on a link or at the end of an ajax call.  Sorry if I did not word properly but I am looking for a way to clear out the div without an explicit 'clear" anchor link, ie clicking outside the box.  From my question: "I have a hunch it is about finding right handler but I don't know to much about handlers."

Comment: @user1904273, there you go

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use

```
document.getElementById('searchresults').textContent="";
```

If you have jquery, then

```
$("#searchresults").empty();
```

Comment: What event handler can I use to trigger this, ie onkeyup or onclick over a region of the page or something? Am trying to avoid having an actual link that says "clear".

Comment: Try '$(document).on("keydown", function(event){ });' and map a keyboard key to it, like DEL. Make sure you call event.preventDefault();.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this right then asking as you only want to clear out one div at a time you can store the id of the element, then when the user clicks somewhere else get the element from the stored id and blank out the textContent. I hope that's what your looking for I may have misunderstood the question.

Comment: I know how to store session variables server side, however, is there an equivalent method client side in JS?  Would prefer not to pass variables back and forth between client and server.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all descendent nodes with something like...

```
var parentNode = document.getElementById('searchresults');

while (parentNode.hasChildNodes()) {
    parentNode.removeChild(parentNode.firstChild);
}
```

Of course, it's simpler with jQuery...

```
$("#searchresults").empty()
```